# random numbers on refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, random

This is my code for generating random numbers and it works fine when it is triggered by a button in my form.

```
        function random() {
            return Math.floor(Math.random() * 100000000);
        }


        window.onload = function(){
            generateRandomNumber();
        }


        function generateRandomNumber(){
            $("#GenerateCode").val(random());
            alert('Reference Code: ' + $('#GenerateCode').val());

        }
```

I am using wizard template in my project. What I want to happen is to generate random numbers when I refresh or when the page Loads adn be displayed in a textbox.
Help please....Thank you...

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using? `.live()` has been depricated.

Comment: Since you're using ASP.NET and need this on page load/refresh - why not use server-side code?

Comment: @Phillip: Not just deprecated, but removed as of v1.9

Comment: so what should i use..?

Comment: is it helpful for you..??
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15731817/faster-javascript-processing

Comment: this might be helpful for you..??
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15731817/faster-javascript-processing

Answer (score 1):

Put this in a script file thats loaded by the page.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#GenerateCode').val(random());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`window.onLoad = function () {$('#GenerateCode').val(random())};`

Comment: where will i put this.?code behind or with the scripts.? @jason Nichols

Comment: I'd put it at the end of your javascript, but in theory, you could put it anywhere there's javascript. shouldn't make a difference.

Answer (score 0):

A more random number after load

```
    $(function() {
        $('#GenerateCode').val(Math.floor(Math.random() * 100000000));
    });
```